# How does compiler know it needs to return an expression tree?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Is it hard-coded into compiler to return an expression tree when it encounters a lambda assigned to Expression <Func<T>> something like following?

Expression<Func<int, int>> exp = n => n;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the C# 5 specification document in section 4.6 "Expression tree types"

> **4.6 Expression tree types**
>   Expression trees permit lambda expressions to be represented as data structures instead of executable
>   code. Expression trees are values of expression tree types of the form
>   `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<D>`, where D is any delegate type.
>   For the remainder of this specification we will refer to these types
>   using the shorthand `Expression<D>`.   If a conversion exists from a
>   lambda expression to a delegate type D, a conversion also exists to
>   the expression tree type `Expression<D>`. Whereas the conversion of a
>   lambda expression to a delegate type generates a delegate that
>   references executable code for the lambda expression, conversion to an
>   expression tree type creates an expression tree representation of the
>   lambda expression.   Expression trees are efficient in-memory data
>   representations of lambda expressionsand make the structure of the
>   lambda expressiontransparent and explicit.  Just like a delegate type
>   D, `Expression<D>` is said to have parameter and return types, which
>   are the same as those of D.   The following example represents a
>   lambda expressionboth as executable code and as an expression tree.
>   Because a conversion exists to `Func<int,int>`, a conversion also
>   exists to `Expression<Func<int,int>>`:
>
> ```
> Func<int,int> del = x => x + 1;                       // Code
> Expression<Func<int,int>> exp = x => x + 1;       // Data
> ```
>
> Following these assignments, the delegate del references a method that
>   returns `x + 1`, and the expression tree exp references a data
>   structure that describes the expression `x => x + 1`.   The exact
>   definition of the generic type Expression as well as the precise
>   rules for constructing an expression tree when a lambda expressionis
>   converted to an expression tree type, are both outside the scope of
>   this specification. Two things are important to make explicit:
>
> - Not all lambda expressionscan be converted to expression trees. For instance, lambda expressionswith statement bodies, and lambda
>     expressionscontaining assignment expressions cannot be represented. In
>     these cases, a conversion still exists, but will fail at compile-time.
>     These exceptions are detailed in §6.5.
> - Expression offers an instance method Compile which produces a delegate of type D:
>
>   `Func<int,int> del2 = exp.Compile();`
>
> Invoking this delegate causes the code represented by the expression
>   tree to be executed. Thus, given the definitions above, del and del2
>   are equivalent, and the following two statements will have the same
>   effect:
>
> ```
> int i1 = del(1);
> int i2 = del2(1);
> ```
>
> After executing this code,  i1 and i2 will both have the value 2.

Answer (score 2):

From the C# specification (6.1.12):

> Anonymous functions and method groups do not have types in and of
>   themselves, but may be implicitly converted to delegate types or
>   expression tree types.

So anonymous function (lambda) does not have type by itself, but when you assign it to the variable of type `Expression` (or pass to the function expecting `Expression` argument) - it is implicitly converted to it (assuming it's possible - not every anonymous function can be converted to expression tree). Same story with delegates - if you pass it to function expecting `Func<int,int>` or assign to variable of such type - it becomes a delegate and not expression tree.

Answer (score 1):

Because the lambda is assigned to an `Expression`.

Comment: So if it is named Mexpression instead, it must be assigned to an Mexpression not Expression? So, is there any documentation about this.

Comment: I added answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

From msdn ;

When a lambda expression is assigned to a variable of type Expression, the compiler emits code to build an expression tree that represents the lambda expression.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx